# How to change font family and font size using google sheet API in php

Tags: php, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I had search much on google and last. I have to be here.
Anyone help us to change google sheet font family and font size using google sheet API.
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Not sure about font family but formatting `text color`, `background color`, `font size` and t`ext justification` can be modified using the [spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate) as mentioned in [Basic Formatting](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/formatting) guide.